# Join multiple row results into one

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I have a problem with combining multiple rows result into one row result by userID.

I get this result:

```
||userID||eventTypeID||COUNT(*)||  
||  1   ||    1      ||    1   ||  
||  1   ||    2      ||    1   ||  
||  2   ||    1      ||    1   ||   
||  3   ||    2      ||    1   ||
```

What I would like to is get it this way:

```
||userID||eventTypeID ONE||COUNT()||eventTypeID TWO||COUNT()||
```

and so on...

I cant figure out how I do this, I have tried pivotSQL and concat, but I can't make it work.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT eventMatch.userID, eventMatch.eventTypeID, COUNT( * )   
FROM  `eventMatch` , activity, activityMatch  
WHERE eventMatch.activityID = activity.activityID  
AND activity.activityID = activityMatch.activityID  
AND activity.khID =1  
GROUP BY eventTypeID, userID  
ORDER BY userID ASC
```

Hopes somebody can help, maybe it is easy, but I have tried looking for solutions for 2 days now:-)

Thanks..

Comment: You may do it by using stored procedure with cursor iteration and result to string append

Comment: How many distinct eventType's there are?

Comment: @Michael - right know there is 3 different eventTypes, but eventTypes is something there is added for time to time, so it changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  eventMatch.userID, 
  SUM(eventMatch.eventTypeID = 1) As TypeOne,
  SUM(eventMatch.eventTypeID = 2) As TypeTwo, 
  COUNT( * )   
FROM  `eventMatch` 
INNER JOIN activity      ON eventMatch.activityID = activity.activityID 
INNER JOIN activityMatch ON activity.activityID = activityMatch.activityID  
WHERE activity.khID =1  
GROUP BY userID  
ORDER BY userID ASC;
```

---

### Update 1

For multiple event types, you can do this dynamically like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(em.eventTypeID = ''',
      em.eventTypeID, ''', 1, 0)) AS Type',
      em.eventTypeID )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  `eventMatch`       AS em;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT em.userID, ', @sql,
                  ', COUNT( * )   
                  FROM  `eventMatch`       AS em
                  INNER JOIN activity      AS  a ON em.activityID = a.activityID 
                  INNER JOIN activityMatch AS am ON a.activityID = am.activityID  
                  GROUP BY em.userID  
                  ORDER BY em.userID ASC  ;');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f60cb/1)

---

### Update 2

If you want to iclude all the types from the `EventTypes` table, even if this type has no matches in the others table, you should get the list of types dynamically in the firs step from this table `EventTypes` instead of getting them from the table `eventmatch` then do the dynamic query the same way as before. Like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(em.eventTypeID = ''',
      em.eventTypeID, ''', 1, 0)) AS Type',
      em.eventTypeID )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  eventTypes       AS em; -- <---------- this is what I changed.


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT em.userID, ', @sql,
                  ', COUNT( * )   
                  FROM  `eventMatch`       AS em
                  INNER JOIN activity      AS  a ON em.activityID = a.activityID 
                  INNER JOIN activityMatch AS am ON a.activityID = am.activityID  
                  GROUP BY em.userID  
                  ORDER BY em.userID ASC  ;');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/712b2/2)

Comment: I believe, that he do not know how many userID's there are, it should be dynamic

Comment: @Michael This should work fine for any userID, it is about how many `eventTypeID` he wants, and in his question he said type one and type two.

Comment: if so, than it is correct, but if eventTypeID distinct count will raise, than he should use stored procedure to be more flexible

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Comment: This answers my quistion, but I havent asked my question right sorry. But as @Michael is saying, the eventTypeID is dynamic, so there will be added more eventTypeID's. So is there a way for doing this?

Comment: @user2046146 Yes, in this case you have to do this dynamically, I will update my answer with the dynamic version. Just give some minutes please.

Comment: The count need to be for each eventTypeID

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - is there a way where I can get all the eventTypeID from the table eventTypes. So if we say that I got 5 eventTypeID, but only 3 eventTypeID has been used, it will still display all the eventTypeID from the eventTypes table, but just with a zero or something? Because, right now it displays only the eventTypeID there is in the eventMatch table. Don't know if you understand my question:-)?

Comment: @user2046146 - Again! You're welcome any time :) Glad I could help :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - here i am again:-) I have a problem with executing this statement. It works fine in phpMyAdmin, but in my program I use PDO, and I can't get this statement to work in that. I then tried to make a stored procedure with the statement, but it wont work eather. Any chance you can make i to a stored procedure? So sorry for troubeling you againg...

Comment: @user2046146 - Its OK, You should write it [**like in this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0a8a/1), note that it is working fine in this demo, but in your pc you might need to define a `DELIMITER` something like this `DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetEventTypesCounts()
BEGIN
-- the same code from my stored proc;
END //
DELIMITER ;`. So try it and if it doesn't work add the delimiter.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - thanks you, it works now. Now I only have one last question, and it is from my co-worker. Is there any way we in our query can get a count, how many activities the userID has signup for. We have a table which name is signup, and there is a activityID, and a userID and a answer, = 1, if the user has attended the activity. Is there any way, we can get a count of how many activities the user has signup, in the same row?

Comment: @user2046146 Sorry this last requirement will depends on how these tables are related, Can you please setup a demo with some sample data. I already created the tables, but I need some sample data. Kindly update [**This demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78f63/1) with some sample data for all the tables and show me the results you are looking for from these tables it will be very helpful.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - The way you have build the tables is the right way. There isn't really a realtions between signup and eventTypes, the relations is between activity and signup, so as you have made. A user signs up to an activity, and then we want a count on how many activity the user have signed up for, if it is possible in the same row as with the eventTypes. It is for sports statistis, so maybe a player have played 10 games, but only scored 1 goal(eventTypes), and made 1 assist(evenTypes).

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - do you have any idea if it is possible to get this in the same result, maybe as this by userID, ||activitySignUpCount||eventType1||eventType2 ..... and so on?

Comment: @user2046146 Sorry for late. I am on work right now :(. Sorry. Any way, your last requirement is too complicated, it is easy to be done, but there are couple of problems. The two columns `UserId`, activityid are both related to each others by two tables. So in the result how do you want to deal with the duplicates for each userid? [**See this fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed27a/1) it will give you what you are looking for, and it is correct output for the sample data, you need to test it and ensure it works fine for you.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - you dont have to say sorry for anything, I'm just glad for your help! The example you have given me almost work perfectly, the only thing there is, is that a user can be signed up for a activity, without having anything in eventMatch table. And I can see that you select from eventMatch, so if a user dont have anything in that table, it wont count his sign up. Is it possible to make it, so it counts the user signup eventhough the user havent any eventMatch for that specific activity? Ex. The user has played the game, but hasn't made evenTypes in eventMatch?

Comment: @user2046146 - Do you mean something [**like this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fbef/1).

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - this dosen't work, because if the user dont have any eventMatch, it wont run the signup part. I would like it to still count that the user have signed up for an activity, eventhough he hasn't any eventTypeID in the eventMatch table. If you look at this fiddle you have made earlier with some new sample data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/072b6/1. You can see that in the signup table, the user with userID 1 has signed up for acitivityID 4, but this dosent get counted, beacuse he dosent have anything in the eventMatch, because he haven't scored any goal or made any assist:-)

Comment: @user2046146 - I think in this case it would be better to do this in a separate query, and if you want to do so any way, you have to do this in a correlated subquery [**like in this updated fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a6d1/1). What do you think?? not that I updated the sample data.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - in the fiddle you have just made, it still fails, if you take ex. all the eventMatch with the userID 3 out from eventMatch. So if we say he have been to 4 activities, his count will not be shown, because he isn't in the eventMatch table. But maybe you are right, that it is better to do it in two queries. But just wanted to hear, if you knew a way in one query:-) THANKS for all your help, it has really helped me alot! Thanks

Comment: @user2046146 - Sorry I couldn't understand, I think my query works fine, but it counts the activityid for each userid from the signup table, so you need to count those from the `eventmatch` instead and test the value of the `answer` from the other table signup? thats why I told you to setup the data, because I am not fully understand your schema and table relations. But for the userid it has only one activity in the signup table with answer = 1.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, I try to play with it a bit... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @user2046146 - You're welcome any time :) Feel free to ask again if any thing goes wrong any time. Good Luck :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - i'm back with a new problem, don't know if you can solve this:-) It is still with the query we made here. The problem is, that I have a table with all the users. So instead of showing only the users that have signed up, I would like to show all the users, and then count how many times they have signed up, and if they have no signed up, they should still be showned, but just with a zero. Don't know if you understand? Or should have more information? Also, if they have no eventMatch, they should still be shown.

Comment: @user2046146 Glad to see you again :) . See [**this updated fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bcfe/1), just `LEFT JOIN` the  table users, this is assuming that there is a table `Users`.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - I think we are very close now, but have to test it:-) Thank you so much for your help - I will contact you with the result:-)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - It worked the thing you gave me:-) But then I have a little extra question, dont know if you can answer:-) When we makes the type1, type2 and so... rows, is there a way to fill them with default 0 for each user?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Dont know if you will see this question, but I hope, because I have a problem I have tried to fix for 2 days now, and maybe you can see the problem. The problem is that i would like to ORDER BY the the Types in my group_concat, but cant find out how? Hopes you see this and can help:-)

Comment: @user2046146 - You can use the `ORDER BY` clause inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function, see the documentation of the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), here is a [**live demo for it**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86722/3), from an old answer of mine. Hope this help :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Maybe i'm just stupid, but I cant figure it out, can I maybe get you to try on this old fiddle you made me? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bcfe/1. I'm so sorry, but i'm close to lose my mind on this:-)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - And also do you know how to Order by a stored procedure variable? Because it is a way the user can sort by, so the order by input comes from the user? I have read about doing it dynamic, but i can't get i to work eather

Comment: @user2046146 - Sorry, it seems I'm stupid, I don't understand what are you trying to do. Are you trying to display the event types in a specific order? note that they are columns' headers, if so you can do it inside group_concat like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bcfe/5 , so it is like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/789d4/1

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - I think it is my explanation there is bad:-) What I would like to do is, if you see this fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a761/2. I would like it to be ORDER BY the value given from the user (the user of the website), which in this case is Type1. It is for at statistic soccer page, so he can choose to order by goals, assist, cards and so on. If you harcode the type in ORDER BY to Type1, then it works, but it wont accept my varialbe?

Comment: @user2046146 - OK, sorry now I understand. Look, this is really bad, you have to be careful, because of SQL Injection, read this article for more info [**The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL**](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) about the danger of dynamic SQL, it might be safe in this case since you are doing this in `ORDER BY` clause, but in general try to avoid this, but if you need to do this any way, it should be `...ORDER BY ', @typeID, '   ;'...` like in [**this fiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81d6e/1).

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - That does the trick! PERFECT - thanks. Such a simple solutions, Thanks:-) I use PDO and prepared statements, so injections shouldn't be a problem, but thanks for the advise! AGAIN THANKS:-)

Answer (score 0):

does

```
GROUP BY eventMatch.userID, eventMatch.eventTypeID
```

the job?